# Contradicting decision nodes in decision tree

Tags: cart

[image]

My balance S is a continous variable. when it is not less than 200000 then it automatically means it is greater than equals to 200000 while decision tree is taking balance S >=200000 as another node. I am trying to predict fraud and non fraud cases. My percentage of correctly predicted is 92% with this decision model. Can anyone please help me with this problem. What is the problem with the decision tree. how should I Correct it??

Comment: Presumably the split points are sufficiently different and just the digits displayed are not sufficient. Try something like `prp(obj, digits = 8)` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. you were right digit displayed were not sufficient. But can I ask you ......does 199.9975e+3 is significantly different from 200.031e+03.if not, then why decision tree is taking these two values as separate nodes??. Balance S is measured in Rupees(Indian currency). I also don't understand coded.ic node. this coded.ic is categorical variable and it has 36 categories. I am not able to interpret it from the above decision tree. Please help me with this problem.